# Как настроить несколько frontend'ов с разными ssl сертификатами в haproxy?

Tags: proxy, https, ssl, frontend

Если нужно настроить несколько фронтендов на 80м порту, это делается так:

```
frontend http-proxy
 bind *:80
 mode http
 acl web1 hdr_beg(host) www.website1.com
 acl web2 hdr_beg(host) www.website2.com
 use_backend http-web2 if web2
 default_backend http-web1
```

Как настроить несколько фронтендов на 443м порту с разными ssl сертификатами?